# Download gzip compressed images from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have the Cloudfront set up to automatically compress objects. I have an image with it's Content-Type metadata set as 'application/opentype' one of the acceptable Content-Type values to enable compression. 
But when I download the Image from S3 (which is configured as an origin for Cloudfront) I see that the request header has 'accept-encoding: gzip' but the image is not gzipped. I want to know how to add gzip compression for an object in S3?

Comment: You might want to ask an actual question here...

Comment: @OpenUserX03 my question is how do I enable gzip on an image in S3. I have followed all the required steps but it still does not gzip